# How to imitate this slides / presentation design?

Tags: web-apps, offline, presentation

First of all,
[*Honestly I don't know how can this be done, what do we call this to be, can we do it by offline software, or online as a webpage..or what. I really don't know*.]

Can you please tell me from where can I be able to imitate such a presentation design and what software or programs or whatever can do so, I want the following features as shown in the short video in (Gofile) link.

Which I will also mention and explain what they are.

The features that I am wishing to copy and imitate as shown in the video in this link https://gofile.io/d/et7WlO. Watch it, read the features, then watch it again and all should be very clear and simple.

1. ***Being able to toggle through the slides using the right & left arrows on the keyboard***. Of course, in order to be able to do that, I had to click in the [selected area], and that's why I did the 'first' click.

   And, the [selected area] is (where the content, text in this case, is shown and displayed), it should be clear after watching it at least once, as all slides are in the same exact area.
2. ***Also, being able to add hyperlinks or objects in the area and within the text*** -as the link I quickly hovered the cursor over-, or directing to a file to be downloaded or an image / button that directs to another slide. Also, being able to add a video in one of the slides. A video in the slides was not shown in this video, since this is just an excerpt of the content.
3. ***Being able to have these squares in the bottom that show how many slides are there to be displayed, also the name of the slide is shown*** as the cursor hovers over the square. Where obviously clicking on the square sends us to the slide.

   ??- [I think this may not be called a feature since it is obvious that such a program or software which has all this for presentation, should also be having like page, sub-page..and so on].

As in: I want to create a chapter or section, then each can include sub-chapters or sub-sections, and each sub-chapter or sub-section has for example 20 slides included.
++ if I can partially shade / color page or slide parts.

So, ***simply the questions are***:

- What kind of software or website provides these features for presentation?
- What are they called ?
- And is this concerned with webpages only or can be imitated on offline programs ?

I just want to know the keyword for this so I can search among all the alternatives myself.

I hope the question is clear, let me know if not.
And of course, if anybody has any suggestion they already know about or would recommend, then that would be most welcome indeed!

I don't care if the software works online or offline, I would still prefer offline software, so I write content and share it like this.

I have noticed some (related questions), they seem related, yet I couldn't help myself much by reading them. So please feel free to delete my question after I get my answer.

Comment: I cannot open the video, so this is probably off the mark. Have a look at https://revealjs.com/ It is quite nice to use

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a web slider that can run on any browser and does not need to be hosted if you do not need it.

Take a look at
[www.jssor.com/demos/](http://www.jssor.com/demos/)
in my opinion one of the best and more versatile sliders.

It can run on mobile or desktop, have different navigation options, arrows, dots, images, and even drag, can have Html content, and can be personalized.

One feature that I do not see included, is the bubble or tooltip over the navigation dot, but I am pretty sure can be added.